# React onClick event not firing when function is passed to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a pretty simple React component where I pass the callback for the `onClick` event to a child element; however, the onClick event does not seem to ever fire. The class is below, `HamburgerMenu` and `Hamburger` are correctly imported/rendered with no events existing on those components.

```
export default class AppHandler extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.state = {
      menuOpen: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HamburgerMenu menuOpen={this.state.menuOpen} />
        <div className="content">
          <nav>
            <Hamburger onClick={this.onMenuChange.bind(this)} />
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  onMenuChange() {
    console.log('onMenuChanged');
    this.setState({ menuOpen: !this.menuOpen });
  }
};
```

I can get it to work if in the `Hamburger` component I set another `onClick` event on the root element and then set `this.props.onClick` as that event handler but that seems like it's unnecessary from everything I have saw.

Any guidance? Thank you!

Comment: It should be `this.onMenuChange.bind(this)`, but you'd at least be getting a console error when you click. You're sure you get absolutely no console error when clicking?

Comment: I do see that there is something actually binded to the `onClick` of the `Hamburger` component but it still does not actually call `onMenuChange`. So it does not throw an error because there is actually something binded, but whatever is binded is not correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this did end up being me not understanding where the `onClick` event is getting attached. Since the component itself is not really an actual element when setting `onClick={this.onMenuChange(this)}` I am only setting `prop.onClick` for the child element `Hamburger`. In order to actually get the bind to work I *do* have to set `onClick={this.props.onClick}` on the root element of the `Hamburger` component.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're exporting an ES6 class and not using `createClass`, you have to bind handlers to `this`:

```
<Hamburger onClick={this.onMenuChange.bind(this)} />
```

See the React docs on [no autobinding](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding) to ready why:

> Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that they don't automatically bind this to the instance. You'll have to explicitly use .bind(this) or arrow functions =>.

Also, you have error with your state. `this.setState({ menuOpen: !this.menuOpen });` will set `this.state.menuOpen`, but since you're not mutating the `prop`, it will never change here: `<HamburgerMenu menuOpen={this.menuOpen} />`.

That line should be:

```
<HamburgerMenu menuOpen={this.state.menuOpen} />

// and you should set a default state as well

// in AppHandler
componentWillMount() {
  this.state = {
    menuOpen: this.props.menuOpen
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction on the state, but even when binding `onClick` to `this`, the `onMenuChange` function is never called.

I do see that there is a function actually blinded to the event through React dev tools but do not see it ever called.

Comment: @BenM, It is called. Read the second part of my answer. You need to use `menuOpen={this.state.menuOpen}` and mutate the state.

Comment: I do see the part about the incorrectly setup state, which I get, but I am logging to the console with the onMenuChange event and there is no output. I updated the example to include the corrections, where the `onClick` does not still fire.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind `this` when you are using component, It's enough to bind `this` in your `<Hamburger />` component. Please see the following sample code

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'components/Button';

class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick(e){
    console.log(e.target);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Button Text="Save" onClick={this.handleClick} />
    );
  }
}

//Button Component
class Button extends React.Component {
  clickEventHandler(e) {
      this.props.onClick(e);
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick="this.clickEventHandler.bind(this)">{this.props.Text}</button>
    );
  }
}
```